# Why is my page displaying in the browser but showing a 404 server response? Is it the htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have built a specific landing page for a site here :
https://www.sunfimmo.com/programmes-immobilier-neuf-la-reunion/le-grand-bleu/

**/le-grand-bleu/** is a directory and the filename is just index.php.

When you access the URL in a browser it displays fine but in Screaming Frog Crawler, Search Console, Lighthouse, etc, it returns a 404 server error.

The main site is a Wordpress site and this page is a standalone basic HTML PHP page that doesn't go through the Wordpress system.

So, I was wondering if the htaccess for Wordpress (see code below) is picking up the url and because it looks like a Wordpress url it triggers the Wordpress rewrite system but can't find that URL and returns the 404.

But ... if that is so, surely the url https://www.sunfimmo.com/programmes-immobilier-neuf-la-reunion/le-grand-bleu/index.php would not trigger the rewrite??

Here's the standard WP htaccess code currently being used

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

As far as I can tell, that htaccess shouldn't trigger the Wordpress rewrite because the directory exists in the first URL I posted and the filename (index.php) exists in the second url.

Has anyone got any ideas what is causing this 404?

Thanks :)

Comment: "When you access the URL in a browser it displays fine" - although it's still returning a 404 response code. As you surmise, this does not appear to have anything to do with your `.htaccess` file (at least, not the one you posted). Do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path?

Comment: Hi. Ok so I just checked that and the answer is no - there's more stuff in the root .htaccess but it's all ExpiresByType and a bunch of Permanent redirects but none of them have any connection to this url

Comment: Create a `dummy.php` and `dummy.html` file(s) in the same directory - do these also return a 404?

Comment: aha! That worked!

Comment: So I renamed "index.php" as "dummy.php" and it returned a 404.

Comment: damn, I keep hitting return! - then I tried commenting out 2 lines `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php' );       
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/wpresidence-child/functions.php' ); ` and it works fine without the 404. So now I just need to figure what in those includes is causing problems. Thanks for your help!